# Illustrator: How to connect a path into another path

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path

I am trying to create this smiley face with sort of brackets at the end of the smile.

That's 3 paths. One for the smile and two for the brackets. All of them only are strokes and don't have fills. (stickman style)

I want to join the end of the smile into the middle of the brackets, on each side, and don't want the smile to become a mouth when I unite them in pathfinder. Is this possible? So far I couldn't find any solutions.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, select all your paths you want to join.

Go to **Object → Path → Join** or **Right Click → Join** or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> to join the paths.

---

You have to make sure that the edges are perfectly aligned with the brackets, best is to enter *Outline Mode* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd>) to perfectly align the anchor points.

---

You can also just group your paths together (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>), unless there is a specific reason you want them *joined*.

Comment: Oh man, so close but yet so far. Thx

Comment: Side note, I would create the smiley out of regular shapes (circles) for better symmetry. [Here's a quick smile I threw together.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R57FV.png)

Comment: That IS better.

Answer (score 1):

A late version: Make a smile brush.

[image]

Draw 2 equal vertical lines and one horizontal line, make a neutral smile. Drag it into the brushes panel and define it to be a new artistic brush

Draw different curves and apply the brush to them. The bottom version is edited from the shape above it. If you expand the appearance of a curve which has got the new brush, the result is editable with the direct selection tool. It's still a group of three separate strokes. Ungrouping it makes the parts independent.

I bet having simply a group of three strokes, as already suggested by others, is good enough for most purposes.

Comment: A virtual thumbs up, actually I was trying to apply a brush from the beginning, but the lines drawn by mouse ended up crooked so I resigned from that. This opens up new horizons, so many more to open... Thx.